# Control blocking input to lower control

Tags: wpf, esri

Hopefully this is a WPF issue and not a esri issue. I have an ESRI map control, and I am placing a control on top of the map. When I do this, the map no longer receives input(I can't move around or click anything). If I modify the z-index of the top control to place it behind the map, the map works fine again.

```
 <Grid Name="MapGrid"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"   >

            <Grid Name="MapGrid"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"   >

        <esri:MapView x:Name="MainMapView" Panel.ZIndex="0"   KeyDown="MyMapView_KeyDown"   MapViewTapped="MyMapView_MapViewTapped"  Map="{Binding Source={StaticResource MapResource}}"   WrapAround="True"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Initialized="MyMapView_Initialized" >
        </esri:MapView>

        <Expander Header="Properties" ExpandDirection="Right" Panel.ZIndex="-1">
            <ItemsControl  Background="Transparent" Height="700" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Name="FeaturePropertyRegion" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="FeaturePropertyRegion" />
        </Expander>

    </Grid>
```

This code works, but if I raise the ZIndex of the Expander pannel, the map no longer receives input. I am assuming the issue has to do with the visual tree of WPF, and how input cascades down. Any ideas on what the issue could be? Thanks.

**EDIT**

The issue seems to be with the expander, as the map works if I remove the expander and just have the ItemsControl.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
    <Expander IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <ItemsControl  />
    </Expander>
```

It doesn't seem to be a problem with extender, which would be very wired if it did 
I tried this :

```
<Grid>

    <Button  />
    <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Left" ExpandDirection="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" Width="525" Height="350"/>
    </Expander>

</Grid>
```

Comment: So this makes the map work, but then obviously I can't expand the expander. The map does work if JUST the ItemsControl is there, so it seems to be an issue with the expander.

Comment: do you wan't to interact with the ItemsControl ?

Comment: Yea. Basically, the ItemsControl has MapProperties, so they need to be able to click the map, and then use the expander to show/hide the map properties of what they clicked.

Comment: Just to clarify the expander poses a problem even when Collapsed ?

Comment: Which is really weird, since one would think that only the expanded part would be blocking the map, but nowhere on the map allows for input if the expander control is being used at all and is on top.

Comment: Interesting. I figured the ESRI Map control may be doing something weird to affect this, but it is still the case that uncommenting the expander makes it work perfectly fine. I don't know what to try from here.